# Testing interdependent Git branches?

Tags: git, git-branch

Consider making a forum and you have a feature branch to implement basic user actions and another feature branch that takes care of displaying posts. I know you would join them into a test branch but I am not exactly sure when. Do I only join them when they are both finished?

I'm really confused about how branch structuring works when testing.

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

There isn't a single, canonical answer that fits all cases, but there are some useful rules of thumb. Branches should generally be independent features, at least to the extent practical. They should be merged into the main line of development, or into an intermediate integration branch, only when completed. There are always exceptions, but this is a widely-accepted model followed by [git-flow](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow) and others.

### Where Unit Tests and Integration Tests Belong

In general, each branch should contain new unit tests that focus on the features unique to that branch. For example, branch *foo* should have unit tests that exercise the *foo* feature, while branch *bar* should contain unit tests that exercise the behavior of *bar*.

When you merge multiple features into a common branch, you may or may not create new behaviors that are more effectively tested with integration tests. Whether this integration testing takes place on a separate branch from your main line of development or not is really a stylistic choice that each project must determine for itself.

### One Branch Per Feature, with Relevant Tests

The thing to remember is that in Git, branching is cheap, so having one branch per feature is often (although not universally) considered a best practice. This is the model followed by [git-flow](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow), for example. Therefore, build your unit tests on the same branch as your features.

As a personal matter, I also recommend adding integration tests that will validate that your new feature integrates properly with its parent branch. Integration tests for features that have not yet been merged with the main line of development will need to be added later, unless you do a lot of cross-pollination between development branches with git-merge and cherry-pick. I wouldn't recommend that for the common case, but your mileage may certainly vary.

Comment: What does TL;DR mean? I assume it is a typo, but it is a large heading, so I am not sure.